# Does socket.emit() automatically stringify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Simple question, does socket.emit() automatically stringify the objects you send over?

If it doesn't, then I need not have to Math.floor certain numbers to shorten the string.

Here is my node.js code:

```
var express = require('express'); //FOR LOCALHOSTING!
var Victor = require('victor');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, listen);

function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("server is up");
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Yes, it will serialise and deserialise all data that you send, though not necessarily using `toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.emit actually passes the data in whatever form you send it in. So if you pass a string you get a string or if you pass an object you get an object:

From the main docs site:
https://socket.io/docs/

```
socket.emit('a message', {
        that: 'only'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
```

From the socket.io cheat sheet:

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

```
socket.emit('hello', 'can you hear me?', 1, 2, 'abc');
```